# jQuery scaling effect

Tags: jquery

I have a lowest price, highest price and present price for a stock. I want to show on a line where the present value is relative to the lowest and highest prices. Is there a way to do it easily in jQuery?

Comment: Your question is extremely vague. Are you looking for a chart of some sort? [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is a nice charting library for jQuery.

Comment: Define visual aspects of your problem. Maybe provide some HTML and tell us how exactly would you like your relation to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

For charts in javascript I'd look at protovis:

http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/

Comment: Wow, Protovis has some really advanced demos.

Comment: Yeah. They should have called it "whoneedsflash".

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for charts i think the best jQuery plugin available is jQuery Sparkline.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sparklines